# Python operation with delimited texts in text file

Tags: python, text, csv

I have a text file called "test.txt" which contains lines in this format.

```
a|b|c|d
a1|b1|c1|d1
a2|b2|c2|d2
a3|b3|c3|d3
```

My intention is to read from that file and give out a list of lists. The result will be something like this.

```
[[a,b,c,d],[a1,b1,c1,d1],[a2,b2,c2,d2],[a3,b3,c3,d3]]
```

I have tried this way:

```
myfile=open('test.txt','r')
x=myfile.readlines()
mylist=[]
mylist2=[]
mylist3=[]

for i in range(len(x)):   
   mylist.append(x[i])

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist2.append(mylist[i].strip())
    mylist3.append(mylist2[i].split('|'))
print mylist3
```

Even though my code work without any problem, i want to know if there is better way( preferably shorter) to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('test.txt','rb') as myfile:
    mylist = list(csv.reader(myfile, delimiter='|'))
```

Even without the module, you can split lines directly without storing the results in intermediary lists all the time:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as myfile:
    mylist = [line.strip().split('|') for line in myfile]
```

Both versions result in:

```
>>> with open('test.txt','rb') as myfile:
...     mylist = list(csv.reader(myfile, delimiter='|'))
... 
>>> mylist
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3']]
>>> with open('test.txt','r') as myfile:
...     mylist = [line.strip().split('|') for line in myfile]
... 
>>> mylist
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3']]
```

Comment: +1 for using `csv` (I would just use `mylist = list(reader)`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.split` and a `list comprehension` here.

```
with open(test.txt) as f:                                                  
    lis = [line.strip().split('|') for line in f]
    print lis
```

**output:**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3']]
```